# Replace a text string in all 'table' environments

Tags: xetex, strings, substitution

I input many tables into a tex file and want to replace "Standard errors in parentheses" in each table with "Any thing I want".

example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}

\input{table.tex}
\input{table.tex}

\end{document}
```

table.tex

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{table \label{tab3}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)E}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)W}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)M}\\
\hline
ln$\chi$            &       3.163\sym{***}&       4.133\sym{***}&       2.017\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.696)         &     (0.451)         &     (0.442)         \\
\hline
FE        &         Y         &         Y         &         Y         \\
N           &        1005         &         980         &         825         \\
R2             &       0.660         &       0.583         &       0.624         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

IDE:Texpad 1.731

Engine: Xelatex, BibTex

Comment: There are probably better ways of doing this than using latex, such as using `sed` from the command line...

Comment: Or global find-and-replace in your editor, if it supports regular expressions. There is no sensible way of doing this during compilation.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting to clarify its objective.

Comment: @Mico How about using \patchcmd or renewcommand?

Comment: @XJ.C - The issue is that the string isn't part of a (LaTeX) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using LuaLaTeX is an option for you, pursuing the approach shown in the following example may work for you. A Lua function, named `dosub`, is set up to perform the string substitution operations, and LaTeX code is provided to limit the operation of this function to `table` environments. Hence, instances of the string "Standard errors in parentheses" that may occur other than inside `table` environments are left untouched.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% create the files 'table1.tex' and 'table2.tex'
\begin{filecontents}{table1.tex}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{A first table \label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)E}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)W}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)M}\\
\hline
$\ln\chi$ & 3.163\sym{***}& 4.133\sym{***}& 2.017\sym{***}\\
          & (0.696)       & (0.451)       & (0.442)       \\
\hline
FE        &   Y           &   Y           &  Y            \\
N         &  1005         &   980         &   825         \\
R\sym{2}  &  0.660        &   0.583       &   0.624       \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table2.tex}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{A second table \label{tab2}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)A}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)B}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)C}\\
\hline
$\ln\chi$ & 3.163\sym{***}& 4.133\sym{***}& 2.017\sym{***}\\
          & (0.696)       & (0.451)       & (0.442)       \\
\hline
FE        &   Y           &   Y           &  Y            \\
N         &  1005         &   980         &   825         \\
R\sym{2}  &  0.660        &   0.583       &   0.624       \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%%\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
%>>>> --- new code starts here ---
\usepackage{luacode,etoolbox}
\begin{luacode}
function dosub ( s )
return ( string.gsub ( s , "Standard errors in parentheses", 
                           "Anything I want" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\directlua{ 
   luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", dosub, "dosub" ) }}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\directlua{ 
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer",  "dosub" ) }}
%<<<< --- new code ends here ---

\begin{document}
\input table1

This instance of ``Standard errors in parentheses'' is not modified.

\input table2
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `grep` and GNU `perl` for this if you are using a Unix-based system. **You will need to know your way around the command line terminal if you plan to replace arbitrary text in an arbitrary number of files.**

*If using a DOS-based, you can just install something like Babun for a quick minimal linux virtual machine and terminal emulator.*

## Setup Simulation in Empty Folder

### 1. Create 10 Tables with Desired String

```
for i in $(echo table{01..10}.tex); do touch $i && echo "Standard errors in parentheses & col2 & col3 \\\\" > $i;done
```

### 2. Use Regular Expression (Perl Dialect) Recursively to List Matches (for the purpose of inspection)

```
grep -Prn 'Standard errors in parentheses'
```

### 3. Replace Text Recursively using Perl and output of Grep

```
perl -i -pe 's/Standard errors in parentheses/whatever/g' $(grep -Prl 'Standard errors in parentheses')
```

---

## Notes

If you want to ensure the replacement is working properly before you write to files, you could write to the terminal.

```
perl -pe 's/Standard errors in parentheses/whatever/g' $(grep -Prl 'Standard errors in parentheses')
```

or save backup with extension .bak

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/Standard errors in parentheses/whatever/g' $(grep -Prl 'Standard errors in parentheses')
```

I have been working with large texts professionally for several years now, and I have experimented with different regular expression language dialects. From my experience, Perl is the most useful and accepted dialect.

- look-aheads and look-backs, which are extremely useful
- non-greedy operator (taming the placeholders like `*` with `?)` e.g You want to find the content of all `\paragraph{...}`s but some other `\macro{}` might be on the same line. Simply type `grep -Prn '\\paragraph\{.*?\}'` to stop at the first `}`.